# Good exposition of tableau for first-order logic with equality?

Tags: reference-request, logic, first-order-logic

I'm looking for a resource (online or printed) that explains in a self-contained way the classic tableau for first-order logic with equality. All I can find are expositions of tableaux for first-order logic without equality, or resources which explains the tableau without equality and then treat equality with the same tableau but by adding axioms, which is ok, but not what I'm looking for.

I'm looking for something that include proofs of soundness and completeness of the tableau.

Any such resource around?